# SQL Server 2008 Format Value in Row depending on criteria

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I couldn't even get close to an answer with my research - perhaps because it is difficult to explain it in a one liner.

Here goes: I have 2 tables in SQL Server, one with the actual "transaction" data, containing a Ratio_ID and another table, also containing the Ratio_ID, but also contains the details on how to format the value eg Amount2 (field is an amount with 2 decimals), Perc0 (field is a percentage with zero decimals).

The "Transaction" data is all in digit format eg. amount is 1.2345 and percentage is 0.0045. We need SQL to use both tables to format the Number field, using the relational Ratio_ID field. In other words, SQL should pick up that row 1 and 10 has Ratio_ID 1, which is an Amount2 field, and it needs to be formatted 1.2345, while rows 2 and 11 might be Ratio_ID 2, which is a percentage, to be formatted 12%.

Hope you can help!

PS. SQL Server 2008 SSMS in use, and the average "transaction" file has just more than 1 million records, making this an extremely important function, which should continue running until the last value.

Comment: You have two problems here. 1) Horrible database design. If you stored the data in the appropriate format in the first place this wouldn't be an issue. 2) This is a presentation issue and as such should be handled in your presentation layer (e.g. report, webpage, form, etc).

Comment: Save as above. Sounds to me like you could maybe use a `CASE` on Ratio_ID, far from ideal.

Comment: I cant disagree, but the data comes from a very basic CSV file, which unfortunately doesnt allow for this.

Comment: Only solution to perhaps move away from CSV to Excel, and have values formatted there somehow?